# How to get overflow text from one frame to go into the frame of the next page's PageTemplate in ReportLab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I can't seem to find this particular need online, but I thought for sure that someone has been able to accomplish this.

I have a ReportLab document (BaseDocTemplate) with one page template on the first page, and a different page template on the second page. The first page template has 6 frames while the second just has one (see the image below).

[image]

What I am trying to accomplish is this: when `direction_frame` has filled with text (which is of unknown size), the overflow text then goes into `direction_frame2` on the second page.

Of course, what's happening now is that overflow text from `direction_frame` is then flowing into `title_frame` on the second page, because the document is duplicating the first page's PageTemplate after it overflows, not having inserted `NextPageTemplate()` and `PageBreak()` into the story at any point.

It seems, then, what I need is either:

1. To find some way to discern the size of each paragraph as it is added to the story so that I can know when it's about to overflow, calling `NextPageTemplate()` and `PageBreak()` at that point, or
2. To find some way to tell ReportLab to flow into `direction_frame2` on `second_page_template` once `direction_frame` is full.

Here are some snippets of code to see how I'm setting this up:

```
# create the page templates
first_page_template = PageTemplate(
    id='first_page_template',
    frames=[title_frame, expected_frame, top_frame_left, top_frame_right, cook_frame, direction_frame])

second_page_template = PageTemplate(
    id='second_page_template',
    frames=[direction_frame2])

# create the document
doc = BaseDocTemplate(
    'print.pdf', 
    pagesize=letter, 
    pageTemplates=(first_page_template, second_page_template)
)

# add the various elements to the story
story = []

... add text to the first 5 frames ...

# add the direction parts as paragraphs
story.append(FrameBreak())
for i in range(len(directions)):
    story.append(Paragraph(directions[i], style=normal_paragraph))
```

I had attempted to move to the next page template after adding x-number of paragraphs, but this is highly inaccurate as the length of each paragraph can vary widely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I found the answer purely by accident. As I was trying different things in my IDE, the argument I needed came up. The solution was to add `autoNextPageTemplate=1` in the arguments for `first_page_template`. This apparently tells the document to automatically switch to the next page template after all the frames on that template have been filled. So, my code wound up being:

```
# create the page templates
first_page_template = PageTemplate(
    id='first_page_template',
    frames=[title_frame, expected_frame, top_frame_left, top_frame_right, cook_frame, direction_frame],
    autoNextPageTemplate=1) # <== This accomplished what I was looking to do ***

second_page_template = PageTemplate(
    id='second_page_template',
    frames=[direction_frame2])

# create the document
doc = BaseDocTemplate(
    'print.pdf', 
    pagesize=letter, 
    pageTemplates=(first_page_template, second_page_template)
)

# add the various elements to the story
story = []

... add text to the first 5 frames ...

# add the direction parts as paragraphs
story.append(FrameBreak())
for i in range(len(directions)):
    story.append(Paragraph(directions[i], style=normal_paragraph))
```

So, I'm leaving this here in case it helps someone else looking to do the same thing.

Edit: It appears that this isn't to be found in ReportLab's document pages on their website, but it does appear in the release notes for version 2.6:

https://docs.reportlab.com/releases/notes/whats-new-26/